# GWT native Drag and Drop: no data in DragOverHandler

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gwt, drag-and-drop, event-handling

> [GWT2.4, Chrome, Firefox]

Hi there,

I'm implementing a drag and drop of tree items in a TreeView. I have a managing class beside my treeview that instantiates items and applies drag n drop handlers.

Here is what it looks like:

```
private CustomTreeItem createItem(Data data){
    CustomTreeItem item = new CustomTreeItem(data);
    if(dndApplicable())
        setupDndHandlers(item);
    return item:
}

private void setupDndHandlers(item){
    // The tree item's widget is a FocusPanel
    FocusPanel wrapper = item.getFocusPanel();

    wrapper.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);

    // Setup the data and drag image when drag starts
    wrapper.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
            event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(wrapper.getElement(), 0, 0);
            event.setData("item_id", item.getData().getId().toString());
        }
    });

    // Each tree item can also be a drop target, so we add handlers accordingly
    wrapper.addDragLeaveHandler(new DragLeaveHandler() {
        public void onDragLeave(DragLeaveEvent event) {
            wrapper.removeStyleName("dragover");
            wrapper.removeStyleName("undroppable");
        }
    });

    // Each tree item can also be a drop target, so we add handlers accordingly
    wrapper.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {
        public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
            if (isDroppable(event.getDataTransfer().getData("item_id"), item))
                wrapper.addStyleName("dragover");
            else
                wrapper.addStyleName("undroppable");
        }
    });

    // Each tree item can also be a drop target, so we add handlers accordingly
    wrapper.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
            String id = event.getDataTransfer().getData("item_id");
            if (isDroppable(id, item)) {
                proceedWithDrop(id, item);
            }
    });
```

}

The `isDroppable` function checks several things, and the first is whether the data is null or empty.

Under firefox, I can access the event data with not problem, but with Chrome, within the DragOverHandler (or a the DragEnterHandler for that matter), the data accessed through the dataTransfer is empty. Within the DropHandler, though, the data is correct.

Am I missings something so obvious I did not see it?

Thanks
O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as-designed, for privacy and security reasons: Chrome implements the HTML5 spec more closely than Firefox here.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#drag-data-store-mode

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I guess I'll have to find another way around to get data about the dragged item.

Cheers!

Comment: Now my tree controller simply stores which item is currently being dragged around (and just to be sure unsets that value on drag end). Works like a charm!